# Python opencv remove noise from captcha

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, captcha

I need to resolve captcha automatically to grab the public data from sites.

I use python and opencv. I'm newbee in solving the images processing. After search, as a method to resolve captcha I came up with next. As the text in Captha uses group of related colours I try to use the HSV format and mask, then convert image to Grayscale and use Threshold (Adaptive_THRESH_MEAN_C) to remove noise from the image.

But this is not enough to remove noise and provide automatic text recognition  with OCR (Tesseract). See images below.

Is there something I can improve in my solution or there is a better way?

Original images:

[image: captcha1]
[image: captcha2]

Processed images:

[image: captcha1]
[image: captcha2]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("1.jpeg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 0, 0), (70, 255,255)) #green
# mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 0, 0), (10, 255, 255))
# mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (125, 0, 0), (135, 255,255))

img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
img[np.where((img == [0,0,0]).all(axis = 2))] = [255,255,255]

img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 2)

cv2.imwrite("out.png", img)
```

Comment: What if you increase you threshold? It looks like the brightness of your text is greater than the noise around it.

Comment: The problem here is that one setting that works for one image won't necessarily work for another. You'd have to constantly change values for different images, which is not very practical. That's the whole point of using captchas.

Comment: I think u should collect more captcha images with labels of symbols in captcha and feed it to deep learning for resolve this task, i am from KZ and I know where this captcha is hanging :)

Comment: Dmitry, Also my friends tell me about mobile app of this site where u wanted automatically grab public data, in mobile version captcha doesn't hanging )))

Answer (score 6):

I think you can reach a good performance by applying some smoothing methods and after that finding image edges.
Here is the code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("input.jpg")
# smoothing the image
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)

#edge detection    
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
cv2.imwrite('output.png', edges)
```

[image] [image]

[image]  [image]

Comment: It definitely enhances the visibility of the characters, but have you tried OCR with that?

Comment: I think you can fill the inside of detected edges using some function like `cv2.floodFill` after that you can pass it to your OCR function.

Comment: Or also you can can use the detected edges for masking your image.

Comment: That's a good idea indeed. After the masking, one would be left with only the characters.

Comment: Careful, if it isn't a close contour (which is not!) then floodfill will just flood everything.

Comment: Salman, thank you. You gave me a great idea. I will try this solution and give feedback.

Comment: How can I deal with https://www.rentbyowner.com/resources/journal/captcha/cT5gcjCLQVUwYNt.png
this type of captcha ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try different approaches to achieve your goal:
Your first image can be processed via the application of a median filter (r=2), followed by adaptive thresholding:
[image: Processed image with clear text]

The binary option of Opening would be another option one could try:
[image: Processed image with clear text. Text is of lower quality than in image one].

Note that the quality is lower than with the first approach (especially the last G is visibily degraded).

The second image responds different to the treatment than the first one:

For the median approach:

[image]

For opening:

[image: Second image]

However, it is possible to extract the text via the application of a median blur (r=1), followed by auto-contrast and then thresholding with 50:

[image: Image two with significantly reduced noise]

As you can see, it is possible to improve the quality of your images enough be recognizable. The first image can be converted to text without problem, but the second one can only be recognized partially.

Comment: can you share the code?