# How to denoise the image

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I'm building an application to recognize some pictures. Below is the example:
[image]

Below is the code I used to convert the picture:

```
img = cv2.imread('9jxs.png', 0)
ret1, th1 = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret2, th2 = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(221), plt.imshow(img, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

Obviously, the result of the picture is "9JXS", my question is how can I delete the noise pix, clean the picture, then I can use OCR components to recognize

Comment: I find the question too general. There are a bunch of options to achieve what you need. As a first approach: You could try changing the threshold values in this line `ret1, th1 = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)` to adjust them to the values of text/noise. although probably the noise comes in different tones each time. If the case is that they are darker always, you could detect them, calculate a contour and remove them from the original image afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python opencv remove noise from captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227287/python-opencv-remove-noise-from-captcha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no simple solution to this problem, otherwise capchas were useless.
You can try to manually tweak the parameters of a range selection combined with some erosion, but I guess this will be very difficult to automate for the general case.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def on_lb_trackbar(val):
    global lb
    lb = val
    cv.imshow(title, cv.erode(cv.inRange(img,lb,ub),erosion_kernel))

def on_ub_trackbar(val):
    global ub
    ub = val
    cv.imshow(title, cv.erode(cv.inRange(img,lb,ub),erosion_kernel))

img = cv.imread(r'udilN.png',cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

lb = 0
ub = 255
title = 'Range selection'
erosion_kernel = np.ones((5,3), np.uint8)

cv.namedWindow(title)
cv.createTrackbar('from', title , lb, 255, on_lb_trackbar)
cv.createTrackbar('to', title , ub, 255, on_ub_trackbar)

on_lb_trackbar(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Stef, thanks for your reply! The picture is very close to final result, I try the number 57 and 198, but can't get the same result, is the picture we used same?

Comment: Yes, it's the picture your posted in your question, I just manually cropped it to remove the axes and re-saved it to the original png file. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXmlk.png) is a version of the original before cropping.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular type of the picture, the lines seem to be much darker compared to the rest of the picture. I'd find the `min()` of the picture and replaced all pixels falling within 10% of minimal value with a mean, or better yet, median value of the neighbours.

Comment: This is a clever approach. Without testing, I'm afraid that that would make the X illegible to ocr

Comment: @MadPhysicist "be not afraid!" (c) =)

Comment: It might be possible to make a histogram of the image and discard everything but the middle peak